# Laravel txt file is not uploading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, I want to upload files like pdf, jpeg, and also txt files etc. I see the uploading is working well with the file extension except .txt files. My code is as under;

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'itemImage' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,png,bmp,svg,doc,docx,odt,xls,xlsx,pdf,txt |max:4096'
]);
```

I also tried by replacing the `txt` as `text/plain` but got the same problem.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What is happening except for "its working except for txt files"? Do you see any other info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `txt` and `|`.

The validation translator will split rules on `|`. However, because of the space, the last extension ends in an extra space. And that is why `.txt` files are not allowed, because they do not end in an extra space.